# Bumpy Upgrade and Possible Missing pakages

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, 14.10

So I just Upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 and It had a few hiccups on the road of no return. Idk if im missing any packages or something failed to install because I got allot of failed attempted installs. How can I check to make sure all packages for the Upgrade were installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and if you get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

you're good to go!

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask